# Why is range behaving not as expected?

Tags: c#, range

I am trying to combine a bunch of integer ranges into one large array like so:

```
List<int> range = Enumerable.Range(65, 90)
                .Concat(Enumerable.Range(97, 122))
                .Concat(Enumerable.Range(48, 57)).ToList();

range.Add(33);

var rangeArray = range.ToArray();
```

The output however contains numbers as if they were summed together like so (**Notice how 91, 92, etc are still there even though they are not in my range.**):

```
65 | 66 | 67 | 68 | 69 | 70 | 71 | 72 | 73 | 74 | 75 | 76 | 77 | 78 | 79 | 80 |
81 | 82 | 83 | 84 | 85 | 86 | 87 | 88 | 89 | 90 | 91 | 92 | 93 | 94 | 95 | 96 |
97 | 98 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 | 105 | 106 | 107 | 108 | 109 | 110 |
 111 | 112 | 113 | 114 | 115 | 116 | 117 | 118 | 119 | 120 | 121 | 122 | 123 | 1
24 | 125 | 126 | 127 | 128 | 129 | 130 | 131 | 132 | 133 | 134 | 135 | 136 | 137
 | 138 | 139 | 140 | 141 | 142 | 143 | 144 | 145 | 146 | 147 | 148 | 149 | 150 |
 151 | 152 | 153 | 154 | 97 | 98 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 | 105 | 106
| 107 | 108 | 109 | 110 | 111 | 112 | 113 | 114 | 115 | 116 | 117 | 118 | 119 |
120 | 121 | 122 | 123 | 124 | 125 | 126 | 127 | 128 | 129 | 130 | 131 | 132 | 13
3 | 134 | 135 | 136 | 137 | 138 | 139 | 140 | 141 | 142 | 143 | 144 | 145 | 146
| 147 | 148 | 149 | 150 | 151 | 152 | 153 | 154 | 155 | 156 | 157 | 158 | 159 |
160 | 161 | 162 | 163 | 164 | 165 | 166 | 167 | 168 | 169 | 170 | 171 | 172 | 17
3 | 174 | 175 | 176 | 177 | 178 | 179 | 180 | 181 | 182 | 183 | 184 | 185 | 186
| 187 | 188 | 189 | 190 | 191 | 192 | 193 | 194 | 195 | 196 | 197 | 198 | 199 |
200 | 201 | 202 | 203 | 204 | 205 | 206 | 207 | 208 | 209 | 210 | 211 | 212 | 21
3 | 214 | 215 | 216 | 217 | 218 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55 | 56 | 5
7 | 58 | 59 | 60 | 61 | 62 | 63 | 64 | 65 | 66 | 67 | 68 | 69 | 70 | 71 | 72 | 7
3 | 74 | 75 | 76 | 77 | 78 | 79 | 80 | 81 | 82 | 83 | 84 | 85 | 86 | 87 | 88 | 8
9 | 90 | 91 | 92 | 93 | 94 | 95 | 96 | 97 | 98 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 10
4 | 33
```

What is happening here, am I misusing the range feature? If anyone has a more efficient solution for this,  I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: `Range(65, 90)` - `90` is the _count_, not the upper bound.

Comment: @AlexD [Facepalm].. I am totally misusing it. Please post it as an answer, and I will accept it ;)

Comment: As @AlexD has said the first parameter is the number to start from and the second one is HOW MANY you want to generate.

Comment: @Alexus Oh, I know it because once I confused myself in a similar way :). (BTW thinking in terms of borders, I would assume that the right one is exclusive, as usual.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second parameter of [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is the *count*, and not the *upper bound*.

Insted, try

```
List<int> range = Enumerable.Range(65, 26)
                  ....
```